# How to create ASP.NET WEB API functional tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rest, testing

I have WEB API project that provides some REST API.
How to write test that runs my service and performs some HTTP requests to it?

Comment: so you want to write Unit Test cases or just want to test WebApi methods?

Comment: I want to write test that requests WEB API method, gets responce and check this responce

Comment: I've updated my answer with detailed explanation, if you still face any issue do let me know, if it's helpful then please upvote and accept it as answered :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add Unit test project to your solution.

[image: Check this image.]

Sample WebApi controller code,

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

Sample WebApi Test project class

```
[TestClass]
    public class ValuesControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Get()
        {
            // Arrange
            ValuesController controller = new ValuesController();

            // Act
            IEnumerable<string> result = controller.Get();

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count());
            Assert.AreEqual("value1", result.ElementAt(0));
            Assert.AreEqual("value2", result.ElementAt(1));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetById()
        {
            // Arrange
            ValuesController controller = new ValuesController();

            // Act
            string result = controller.Get(5);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("value", result);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Post()
        {
            // Arrange
            ValuesController controller = new ValuesController();

            // Act
            controller.Post("value");

            // Assert
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Put()
        {
            // Arrange
            ValuesController controller = new ValuesController();

            // Act
            controller.Put(5, "value");

            // Assert
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Delete()
        {
            // Arrange
            ValuesController controller = new ValuesController();

            // Act
            controller.Delete(5);

            // Assert
        }
    }
```